# MacBook gets heated up

Tags: performance, activity-monitor

I am running on macbook pro 2015. Since, few days, I have noticed a significant degradation in it's performance. Here is the screen shot of the activity Monitor. Can someone please help me on, how can I get rid of this issue

[image: Activity Monitor Screen Shot]

Comment: Is `nessusd` associated with your Android development or is it indeed the Tennant Security Nessus network security system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Mac isn't a corporate managed machine I'd go for uninstalling the Tenable Security Nessus software.

Others might have a different feeling about this but you don't need additional security software on OSX.  We run a Mac-only office for years and the only additional security thing we stick with is the 'Little Snitch' firewall app.

I wouldn't have a clue whether the Nessus software has an uninstall app available but if not, try to get rid of these folders:

```
/Library/Nessus
/Applications/Nessus
/Library/Receipts/Nessus*
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution. But isn't their any other way, besides uninstalling nessus?

Comment: @M.S.P I would uninstall Nessus. You really don't need special security software, email clients, servers, and web browsers today are all pretty secure, as is OS X which won't run an application from a 3rd party without permission. You could try re-installing it to see if it helps, but if it's using 300% of your CPU, there's your problem.

Comment: @M.S.P you can quit or force quit the process. However, if it comes back on again with the same super high usage you'll have to uninstall it.

Comment: That worked out for me. However, I am not using nessus for protecting my system.

Comment: A small Google search learned me you're not the only one that had Nessus installed without knowing.  Why they have it on their system is however not clear, nobody seems to know.  Anyway, get rid of it!